# R C5.0 set metric for skewed data (F1 measure maybe?)

Tags: r, r-caret

I have highly skewed data with non-binary (three classes) target variable. I'd like to train a C5.0 decision tree classification with the R package `C5.0` and optional `caret`. How can I set a metric that works for this kind of data. I thought about using F1. I build a custom function for `caret` + `rpart`, but I don't know how to do it for C5.0. Maybe that is not even necessary, because C5.0 might already be able to deal with skewed data (honestly I'm not quite sure how the implementation works exactly).

Here my code for `caret` with `rpart`:

```
harmonicF1 <- function(data, lev, model) {
  #treats the vectors like classes
  #data$obs and data$pred must be whole numbers
  scores <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(lev))
  names(scores) <- lev
  for(i in lev){
    tp=nrow(data[data$pred==i & data$obs==i,]);        
    fp=nrow(data[data$pred==i & data$obs!=i,]);
    fn=nrow(data[data$pred!=i & data$obs==i,]);
    f1=(2*tp)/(2*tp+fp+fn)
    scores[i]=f1;
  }
  harmonicF1 = 1/mean(1/scores)
  names(harmonicF1) <- "harmonicF1"
  return(harmonicF1);
}
fitControl <- trainControl(summaryFunction = harmonicF1)
fitModel_rpart <- train(cut ~ ., diamonds, method = "rpart", trControl = fitControl, metric = "harmonicF1", maximize=TRUE)
```